# Mongodb updating parent & parent's parent & so fro

Tags: mongodb, database-schema, node-mongodb-native

I have a hypothetical model below, with node-mongodb-native-drive

A01 has a direct child (A03), a grandchild (A04) and a great grandchild (A05): A01 -> A03 -> A04 -> A05

A02 has a direct child (A06)

If a child get a score, all the parents get it. For example, if I give a score to A05, all the parents (A01 to A04) will get a score

```js
[{
  _id: 'A01',
  p_id: '', // parent _id
  score: 0,
}, {
  _id: 'A02',
  p_id: '',
  score: 0,
}, {
  _id: 'A03',
  p_id: 'A01',
  score: 0,
}, {
  _id: 'A04',
  p_id: 'A03',
  score: 0,
}, {
  _id: 'A05',
  p_id: 'A04',
  score: 0,
}, {
  _id: 'A06',
  p_id: '',
  score: 0,
}, 
{
  _id: 'A07',
  p_id: 'A02',
  score: 0,
}, {
  _id: 'A08',
  p_id: '',
  score: 0,
}]


// my naive implementation
function updateScore({ _id, score }) {
  return db.collection
    .findOneAndUpdate({ _id: }, { $inc: { score } })
    .then(function ({ value }) {
      if (value && value.p_id) return updateScore({ _id: value.p_id, score }) // recursively update the parent score
      return Promise.resolve() // if no parent is found
    })
    .catch(function (error) {})
}

updateScore({ _id: 'A05', score: 1 })
```

In my naive function, the application send a query (to increase the score of A05 by 1) to the mongo server. The mongo server receives the query and runs it, returns the some data to the application. The application checks if there is a parent _id, if so it will then send the query to the mongo server. The process repeats till there is no parent _id.

My thought is that sending data back and fro between the application and the mongo server is not the best option due to (1) latency if the mongo server is hosted remotely, (2) consuming bandwidth if the data are huge.

I looked at [bulkWrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/), but it cannot update when it doesn't know the p_id

I looked at [running js file in mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/) which indicates "connection is fast with low latency" and [Store a JavaScript Function on the Server](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/) but it say "Do not store application logic in the database." and may not be as "fast".

So the question: What is the "best" way in this situation, updating the score for all the parents.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider...

- Using a graph database instead that allows these sorts of updates natively.
- Adding some other field like "family_id" so that you can do a single multi-update: `db.collection.update({"family_id": "123"}, { $inc: { score } })`.
- Similar to above, storing a list of parents for each child. This could get you down to two updates (find and update child; update all parents).

In any case, you could also consider *not* updating the parents' scores, but instead summing their children when you need to calculate the score. With some schema changes you can use the aggregation pipeline for this. This would be more efficient if you increment often and query rarely.